# 'objc_ownership' attribute argument not supported: 'assign'

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

In Xcode, in an ARC-enabled project, any attempt to create a weak pointer to any object generates the following warning:

_'objc_ownership' attribute argument not supported: 'assign'_

Testing reveals that the affected variable is being treated as 'strong'.

[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/osr588ln5c6j23o/Screenshot%202014-01-16%2015.53.22.png)

[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gjtrmzhwr18n667/Screenshot%202014-01-16%2017.08.15.png)

What does this warning represent? How do I fix the underlying problem?

*Note:* I am aware that most people declare weak pointers in ObjC with a leading storage qualifier. For the purposes of this question, please assume that *either*  NSObject *__weak foo, *or* __weak NSObject *foo will generate the warning.

Comment: What is the inheritance hierarchy for your `LBXLibraryRootViewController`? And can you confirm that `self` is a `LBXLibraryRootViewController *`?

Comment: LBXLibraryRootViewController inherits from UIViewController. I can confirm that _self_ is a LBXLibraryRootViewController.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code shown looks fine. There's probably something wrong somewhere else in your code.

My guess is that somebody wrote this in one of the header files that you are including:

```
#define weak assign
```

which generates this:

```
% cat test.m
#define weak assign
id __weak x;
% clang -fobjc-arc test.m
test.m:2:4: warning: 'objc_ownership' attribute argument not supported: 'assign'
      [-Wignored-attributes]
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thank you, Greg. If you're ever in Berkeley, the beer's on me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

Comment: It makes no difference: the warning persists.

Comment: `Type * __weak` is actually the correct syntax. compiler will let you use `__weak Type *` just because everyone are using the "wrong" syntax